# Get href of an <a> element inside of a html table

Tags: python, web-scraping

[HTML website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAu5x.png)

I have a HTML list and from this list I only want the `<tr>` elements which have `class=""`. I want to download the files later, so I would only need the third `<td>` and inside of this the `href` of `<a>` element later, how can I read these out directly as a string?

I want all `<tr>` elements with `class = ""`.

For example:

```
<tr class="">
<td>29 September, 2021</td>
<td>Antwerp</td>
<td><a href="http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/listings.csv.gz" onclick="var that=this;ga('send','event', 'download','listings',this.href);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">listings.csv.gz</a></td>
<td>Detailed Listings data for Antwerp</td>
```

And inside of this `<tr>` element there is a `<td>` element. I want inside that third `<td>` element the href of the `<a>` element. So what I want is the url `http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/listings.csv.gz` (not only this :D, I want all urls)

code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

DATASET_URL = "http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html"
DATASET_CITY = "Antwerp"
r = requests.get(DATASET_URL)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
antwerp_table = soup.find(class_=DATASET_CITY.lower())
        
print(antwerp_table)
# antwerp_table is my html table
```

html example (visit for more information http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html)

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-striped antwerp">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-md-3" data-field="host_id">Date Compiled</th>
<th class="col-md-3" data-field="host_id">Country/City</th>
<th class="col-md-3" data-field="host_id">File Name</th>
<th class="col-md-3" data-align="right" data-field="count">
                        Description
                    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="">
<td>29 September, 2021</td>
<td>Antwerp</td>
<td><a href="http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/listings.csv.gz" onclick="var that=this;ga('send','event', 'download','listings',this.href);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">listings.csv.gz</a></td>
<td>Detailed Listings data for Antwerp</td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
<td>29 September, 2021</td>
<td>Antwerp</td>
<td><a href="http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/calendar.csv.gz" onclick="var that=this;ga('send','event', 'download','calendar',this.href);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">calendar.csv.gz</a></td>
<td>Detailed Calendar Data for listings in Antwerp</td>
</tr>
...
<tr class="archived">
<td>17 August, 2021</td>
<td>Antwerp</td>
<td><a href="http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/calendar.csv.gz" onclick="var that=this;ga('send','event', 'download','calendar',this.href);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">calendar.csv.gz</a></td>
<td>Detailed Calendar Data for listings in Antwerp</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first we get all `<tr>`'s with `class=""`, then take all `<a>`'s and finally get all `href`'s

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

DATASET_URL = "http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html"
DATASET_CITY = "Antwerp"
c = requests.get(DATASET_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
trs = soup.find(class_=DATASET_CITY.lower()).find_all('tr', class_='')
hrefs = [a for k in [tr.find_all('a') for tr in trs] for a in k]
links = [x.get('href') for x in hrefs]
print(links)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to get the *not archived* `href` I suggest caused by the structure of the table to work with the `bs4` css selector that gets all `<tr>` with an empty `class` and an `<a>` included:

```
soup.select(f'.{DATASET_CITY.lower()} tr[class=""] a')
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

DATASET_URL = "http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html"
DATASET_CITY = "Antwerp"
r = requests.get(DATASET_URL)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
antwerp_table = [url['href'] for url in soup.select(f'.{DATASET_CITY.lower()} tr[class=""] a')]
```

#### Output

```
['http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/listings.csv.gz',
 'http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/calendar.csv.gz',
 'http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/data/reviews.csv.gz',
 'http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/visualisations/listings.csv',
 'http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/visualisations/reviews.csv',
 'http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/visualisations/neighbourhoods.csv',
 'http://data.insideairbnb.com/belgium/vlg/antwerp/2021-09-29/visualisations/neighbourhoods.geojson']
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to get the table alone
if you use find its going to find all of the tables
i checked there is 1 table with that class so we can use `.select_one()`
after that you have to `select()` `<a>` elements
this is a working code of what you want

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

DATASET_URL = "http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html"
DATASET_CITY = "Antwerp"
r = requests.get(DATASET_URL)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
antwerp_table = soup.select_one(f".{DATASET_CITY.lower()}")
for i in antwerp_table.select("a"):
    print(i.get("href"))
```

Comment: Take another look at your approach, in my opinion it does not give the expected result.

Comment: i tested before post it here and it worked

Comment: yes you are right i didn't see there is more tr with archived class

Comment: Code is still working, but what I mean is the expected result. You are printing not only the links from `<tr>` with `class=""` your result also includes these with `class="archived"` and that was not the goal. By the way, like the f-string syntax you used.

Answer (score 0):

iterate the table results to find the links

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

DATASET_URL = "http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html"
DATASET_CITY = "Antwerp"
r = requests.get(DATASET_URL)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
antwerp_table = soup.find(class_=DATASET_CITY.lower())
        
#print(antwerp_table)
rows = (antwerp_table.find_all('tr', class_=''))
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cols) >= 4:
        link = cols[2].find('a').get('href')
        print link
```